# Get id of a visible Div, failed in all methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

am trying to get the visible Div id of my first spinning wheel , Always am getting the value as 0. I want the exact id of visible part. Any help would be appreciated

> $("div.slot").not(":hidden").prop("id");

Used above code, But am getting the result.

```js
//note parseInt
//note stop
var person = ['Mom','Dad','Friend','Teacher'];
var situation = ['Driving','Walking','chatting','Watching'];
var clicks = true;
var spinCount = 0;
var lifeCount = 4;
function go(){
 addpersonSlots($("#slots_a .wrapper"));
 moveSlots($("#slots_a .wrapper"),'a');
 addSituationSlots($("#slots_b .wrapper"));
 moveSlots($("#slots_b .wrapper"));
}

$(document).ready(
 function(){
  addpersonSlots($("#slots_a .wrapper"));
  addSituationSlots($("#slots_b .wrapper"));
 }  
);

function addpersonSlots(jqo){
 for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  var ctr = Math.floor(Math.random()*person.length);
  jqo.append("<div class='slot' id="+i+">"+person[ctr]+"</div>");  
 }
}

function addSituationSlots(jqo){
 for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  var ctr = Math.floor(Math.random()*situation.length);
  jqo.append("<div class='slot' id="+i+">"+situation[ctr]+"</div>");  
 }
}

function moveSlots(jqo){
  var time = 1000;
  time += Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
  jqo.stop(true,true);
  var marginTop = parseInt(jqo.css("margin-top"), 10)  
  marginTop -= (7 * 100)  
  jqo.animate(
  {"margin-top":marginTop+"px"},
  {'duration' : time, 'easing' : "linear"}).promise().done(function ()
  {
    alert($("div.slot").not(":hidden").prop("id"));
  });
}
```

```css
.first-step-div{
 background:#dddddd;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 padding:80px 0px;
 position:relative;
}
#back_link{
 position: absolute;
 left: 34px;
 bottom: 28px;
}
.problem-count{
 height:45px;
 width:50px;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 background:#e7e8e9; 
}
.problem-count span{
 position: relative;
 top: 4px; 
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:700;
} 
.label-text{
 font-size:20px;
 color:#444;
 font-weight:600;
}
.earned-dibbs{
 font-size:40px;
 font-weight:600;
}
.problem-count.active{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 background:#fff !important; 
}
.sticky-notes{
 padding:30px;
}
.round-1{
 background:#fff;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:15px;
 width:320px;
 padding:50px 0px;
}
.problem-text{
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 376px;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 15px;
 color:#58585a; 
 min-height: 172px;
 max-height:172px;
}
.problem-user-icon{
 height:25px;
 width:25px;
 background:#18b1a0;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.round-label{
 font-size:30px;
 color:#f05f9d;
 font-weight:700;
}
.round-label-text{
 font-size:24px;
 color:#18b1a0;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.count-knowls div{
 display:inline;
}
.knowls-num, .dibbs-num{
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:700;
}
.spin-title{
 font-size:20px;
 padding:8px 15px;
 text-align:center;
 background:#ddd;
 border-radius:10px;
 font-weight:700;
 width:268px;
 position: relative;
 top: 8px;
}
.title-border{
 border:5px dotted #999;
}
.page-header{
 margin:0px;
}
#rcorners_parent {
position: relative;
background: #ddd;
padding: 20px; 
border-radius: 15px 50px 50px 15px / 8% 80% 80% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 42px 0px 32px 0px;
}
#rcorners_parent::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 25px;
height: 80%;
background-color: #bdbec0;
border-radius: 100%;
}

#slots_a {
position: relative;
background: #fff;
padding: 20px; 
width: 170px;
height: 100px;   
border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px / 8% 80% 80% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
}
#slots_a::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 25px;
height: 80%;
background-color: #109582;
border-radius: 100%;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
} 

#slots_b {
position: relative;
background: #fff;
padding: 20px; 
width: 225px;
height: 100px;   
border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px / 8% 80% 80% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
}
#slots_b::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 25px;
height: 80%;
background-color: #109582;
border-radius: 100%;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
} 

#slots_c {
position: relative;
background: #18b1a0;
padding: 20px; 
width: 225px;
height: 100px;   
border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px / 8% 80% 80% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
display:inline-block;
}
#slots_c::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 25px;
height: 80%;
background-color: #109582;
border-radius: 100%;
display:inline-block;
}
.slot {
 font-size:32px;
}
.slots .wrapper{
 margin-top:6px;
 width:100px;

}
.slots .slot{
 width:100px;
 height:117px;
 text-align:center;
}
.spin-person{
 font-size:16px;
}
.nob-img{
 position: absolute;
 top: 18px;
 right: -26px;
}

.spin{
 background:#18b1a0 !important;
 border:1px solid #18b1a0 !important;
 color:#fff !important;
 font-weight:600 !important;
}
.spin:hover{
 background:#18b1a0 !important;
 border:1px solid #18b1a0 !important;
 color:#fff !important;
 font-weight:600 !important;
}
.spin-button{
 padding:10px 34px;
 border-radius:14px;
 font-weight:600;
 font-size:20px;
}
.pink{
 background:#f05f9d;
 border:1px solid #f05f9d;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:600;
}
.pink:hover{
 background:#f05f9d;
 border:1px solid #f05f9d;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:600;
}
.pink-button{
 padding: 10px 11px;
 border-radius: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.step-one, .step-two{
 background:#e1e65d !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#fff;
 border-color:#e1e65d !important;
 font-weight:600;
 padding:10px 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.step-three{
 background:#f05e9d !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#fff;
 border-color:#f05e9d !important;
 font-weight:600;
 padding:10px 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.step-four{
 background:#54cbec !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#fff;
 border-color:#54cbec !important;
 font-weight:600;
 padding:10px 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.glyphicon-triangle-bottom{
 position:relative;
 top:4px;
}
.gif-title{
 color:#f074a9;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:600;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:10px;
}
.col-centered{
 float: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.gif-box{
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.gif-box:hover{
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.orange-button{
 padding:10px 34px;
 border-radius:14px;
 font-weight:600;
 font-size:20px;
}
.btn-container{
 margin:18px 0px;   
}
.draw-steps{
 border:2px dashed #666;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.step-num{
 color:#666;
 font-size:50px;
 font-weight:600;
 position:relative;
 top:10px;
}
.idea-steps-label{
 font-size:18px;
 text-align:left;
}
.draw-title{
 color:#54cbec;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:left;
 font-weight:600;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration:none !important;
}
.btn.grey {
 background: grey none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border-color: grey;
 color: #fff;
 cursor:not-allowed !important;
 pointer-events:auto !important;
}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left{
 left: -10px;
}

#back_link .glyphicon{
 font-size:48px !important;
 color:#818285 !important;
}
#back_link .glyphicon:hover{
 color:#2abbb5 !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 #back_link {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  left:5px;
 }
 #back_link .glyphicon{
  font-size:35px !important;
 }
 .step-one, .step-two, .step-three, .step-four{
  font-size:18px;
 }  
}

.sticky {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 8px 10px;
 width:205px;
 height:200px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 border:1px #E8Ds47 solid;
 background:#f2f4ce;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
 -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
}
.sticky p {
 text-align: center;
}
.sticky textarea {
 width:184px;
 height:180px;
 background:#f2f4ce;
 border-bottom:none !important;
}
.sticky ol {
 margin: 12px;
}
.r-index{
 z-index: 0;
}
.a-index{
 z-index: 99;
}
.sticky-container {
  position: relative;
}
.sticky {
  position: absolute;
}
/*time container*/
button[data-setter] {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #F7958E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[data-setter]:hover { opacity: 0.5; }

.time-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.setters {
  position: absolute;
  left: 85px;
  top: 75px;
}

.minutes-set {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 28px;
}

.seconds-set { float: right; }

.controlls {
 position: absolute;
 left: 37%;
 top: 52px;
 text-align: center;
}

.display-remain-time {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 32px;
 color: #fff;
}

#pause {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.play::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 22px solid #F7958E;
}

.pause::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 5px solid #F7958E;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#pause:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

.e-c-base {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 4px
}

.e-c-progress {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #18b1a0;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.7s;
}

.e-c-pointer {
  fill: #FFF;
  stroke: #F7958E;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#e-pointer { transition: transform 0.7s; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 0.7s; }
.sticky-note-div{
 background:#f2f4ce;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
 height:215px;
 width:22%;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:2%;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 position:relative;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.sticky-note-div img{
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top: 5px;
}
.sticky-note-div:last-child{
 margin-right:0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nob-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  right: -26px;
 }
 #slots_a {
  width:160px;
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 #slots_b {
  width:205px;
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 #slots_c {
  width:205px;
  margin-right:0px;
 }
 .time-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    .nob-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 262px;
  right: -22px;
 }
 #slots_a, #slots_b, #slots_c {
  width:210px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
 }
 .problem-text{
  visibility:hidden;
 }
}
.card{
 background:#fff;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}
.card .tab-content{
 max-width:100% !important;
 font-size:18px !important;
 min-height: 300px;
 max-height:514px;
 overflow: auto;
}
.card .nav-tabs { border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD; }
.card .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover { border-width: 0; }
.card .nav-tabs > li > a { border: none; color: #ffffff;background: #58585a; font-size:16px;font-weight:600;}
.card .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li > a:hover { border: none;  color: #58585a !important; background: #fff; }
.card .nav-tabs > li > a::after { content: ""; background: #58585a; height: 2px; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: -1px; transition: all 250ms ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease 0s; transform: scale(0);-webkit-transform: scale(0); }
.card .nav-tabs > li.active > a::after, .nav-tabs > li:hover > a::after { transform: scale(1);-webkit-transform: scale(1); }
.card .tab-nav > li > a::after { background: #58585a none repeat scroll 0% 0%; color: #fff; }
.card .tab-pane { padding: 15px 0; }
.card .tab-content{padding:20px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;">
<div id="rcorners_parent">
<div class="slots"  id="slots_a">
<div class="wrapper" ></div>
</div>
<div class="slots"  id="slots_b">
<div class="wrapper" ></div>
</div>           
<div id="spin_btn_div">
<div class="btn-container" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<button id="proceed_btn"  style="display:none;font-size:20px;" class="btn pink pink-button shooter-btn" onClick="go();">Proceed</button>
<button id="spin_btn" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;" class="btn spin spin-button shooter-btn" onClick="go();">Spin</button>
</div>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of `prop()` use `attr()` to get the ID

Comment: hmmm, No it is giving it parents id

Comment: to get the current id then use `this` context

Comment: Tried but not getting the result as expected @Tschallacka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out the added function `intersectRect`, which tests if two bounding boxes intersect, and the function to get the visible slots `getVisibleSlot`.

I also modified the logic of your go function, to define the promise handler there because I needed a scope variable.

I added in the comments the logic I thought out.

```js
//note parseInt
//note stop
function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
  return !(r2.left > r1.right || 
           r2.right < r1.left || 
           r2.top > r1.bottom ||
           r2.bottom < r1.top);
}

function getVisibleSlot($parent) {
    var boundingRect = $parent.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    $found = null;
    /** last one to pass te test is the one. 
        this is because the element above the visible one will have a tiny portion 
        visible.
        but the .each parses from "top to bottom" so the last match is the right one, 
        because the element under the "visible" element will not test as visible.
     **/
    $parent.find('div.slot').each(function(index, element) {
        // get the bounding boxes.
        
       
       var newRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
       
       // check for overlap(if it's visible)
       if(intersectRect(boundingRect, newRect)) {
          $found = $(element);
       }
       
       });
   
   return $found;
}

var person = ['Mom','Dad','Friend','Teacher'];
var situation = ['Driving','Walking','chatting','Watching'];
var clicks = true;
var spinCount = 0;
var lifeCount = 4;
function go(){
  var run = 0;
  var done = function ()
      { 
           /**
             only run when the second wheel is done spinning.
             defined here so we can make use of a scoped variable run to count the number
             of completed animations.
             Needed to define here, because they use a random time to spin.
           */
           if(run >= 1) {
              
              var $person = getVisibleSlot($('#slots_a'));
              var $situation = getVisibleSlot($('#slots_b'));
              console.log($person.text(),'is',$situation.text());
           }
           else {
              run++;
           }
        };
 addpersonSlots($("#slots_a .wrapper"));
 moveSlots($("#slots_a .wrapper"),done);
 addSituationSlots($("#slots_b .wrapper"));
 moveSlots($("#slots_b .wrapper"),done);
}

$(document).ready(
 function(){
  addpersonSlots($("#slots_a .wrapper"));
  addSituationSlots($("#slots_b .wrapper"));
 }  
);

function addpersonSlots(jqo){
 for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  var ctr = Math.floor(Math.random()*person.length);
  jqo.append("<div class='slot' id="+i+">"+person[ctr]+"</div>");  
 }
}

function addSituationSlots(jqo){
 for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  var ctr = Math.floor(Math.random()*situation.length);
  jqo.append("<div class='slot' id="+i+">"+situation[ctr]+"</div>");  
 }
}

function moveSlots(jqo, complete){
  var time = 1000;
  time += Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
  jqo.stop(true,true);
  var marginTop = parseInt(jqo.css("margin-top"), 10)  
  marginTop -= (7 * 100)  
    
  jqo.animate(
  {"margin-top":marginTop+"px"},
  {'duration' : time, 'easing' : "linear"}).promise().done(complete);
     
}
```

```css
.first-step-div{
 background:#dddddd;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 padding:80px 0px;
 position:relative;
}
#back_link{
 position: absolute;
 left: 34px;
 bottom: 28px;
}
.problem-count{
 height:45px;
 width:50px;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 background:#e7e8e9; 
}
.problem-count span{
 position: relative;
 top: 4px; 
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:700;
} 
.label-text{
 font-size:20px;
 color:#444;
 font-weight:600;
}
.earned-dibbs{
 font-size:40px;
 font-weight:600;
}
.problem-count.active{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 background:#fff !important; 
}
.sticky-notes{
 padding:30px;
}
.round-1{
 background:#fff;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:15px;
 width:320px;
 padding:50px 0px;
}
.problem-text{
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 376px;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 15px;
 color:#58585a; 
 min-height: 172px;
 max-height:172px;
}
.problem-user-icon{
 height:25px;
 width:25px;
 background:#18b1a0;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.round-label{
 font-size:30px;
 color:#f05f9d;
 font-weight:700;
}
.round-label-text{
 font-size:24px;
 color:#18b1a0;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.count-knowls div{
 display:inline;
}
.knowls-num, .dibbs-num{
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight:700;
}
.spin-title{
 font-size:20px;
 padding:8px 15px;
 text-align:center;
 background:#ddd;
 border-radius:10px;
 font-weight:700;
 width:268px;
 position: relative;
 top: 8px;
}
.title-border{
 border:5px dotted #999;
}
.page-header{
 margin:0px;
}
#rcorners_parent {
position: relative;
background: #ddd;
padding: 20px; 
border-radius: 15px 50px 50px 15px / 8% 80% 80% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 42px 0px 32px 0px;
}
#rcorners_parent::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 25px;
height: 80%;
background-color: #bdbec0;
border-radius: 100%;
}

#slots_a {
position: relative;
background: #fff;
padding: 20px; 
width: 170px;
height: 100px;   
border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px / 8% 80% 80% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
}
#slots_a::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 25px;
height: 80%;
background-color: #109582;
border-radius: 100%;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
} 

#slots_b {
position: relative;
background: #fff;
padding: 20px; 
width: 225px;
height: 100px;   
border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px / 8% 80% 80% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
}
#slots_b::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 25px;
height: 80%;
background-color: #109582;
border-radius: 100%;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:15px;
} 

#slots_c {
position: relative;
background: #18b1a0;
padding: 20px; 
width: 225px;
height: 100px;   
border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px / 8% 80% 80% 8%;
overflow: hidden;
display:inline-block;
}
#slots_c::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: -15px;
width: 25px;
height: 80%;
background-color: #109582;
border-radius: 100%;
display:inline-block;
}
.slot {
 font-size:32px;
}
.slots .wrapper{
 margin-top:6px;
 width:100px;

}
.slots .slot{
 width:100px;
 height:117px;
 text-align:center;
}
.spin-person{
 font-size:16px;
}
.nob-img{
 position: absolute;
 top: 18px;
 right: -26px;
}

.spin{
 background:#18b1a0 !important;
 border:1px solid #18b1a0 !important;
 color:#fff !important;
 font-weight:600 !important;
}
.spin:hover{
 background:#18b1a0 !important;
 border:1px solid #18b1a0 !important;
 color:#fff !important;
 font-weight:600 !important;
}
.spin-button{
 padding:10px 34px;
 border-radius:14px;
 font-weight:600;
 font-size:20px;
}
.pink{
 background:#f05f9d;
 border:1px solid #f05f9d;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:600;
}
.pink:hover{
 background:#f05f9d;
 border:1px solid #f05f9d;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:600;
}
.pink-button{
 padding: 10px 11px;
 border-radius: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.step-one, .step-two{
 background:#e1e65d !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#fff;
 border-color:#e1e65d !important;
 font-weight:600;
 padding:10px 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.step-three{
 background:#f05e9d !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#fff;
 border-color:#f05e9d !important;
 font-weight:600;
 padding:10px 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.step-four{
 background:#54cbec !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#fff;
 border-color:#54cbec !important;
 font-weight:600;
 padding:10px 15px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.glyphicon-triangle-bottom{
 position:relative;
 top:4px;
}
.gif-title{
 color:#f074a9;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:600;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:10px;
}
.col-centered{
 float: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.gif-box{
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.gif-box:hover{
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.orange-button{
 padding:10px 34px;
 border-radius:14px;
 font-weight:600;
 font-size:20px;
}
.btn-container{
 margin:18px 0px;   
}
.draw-steps{
 border:2px dashed #666;
 border-radius:10px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.step-num{
 color:#666;
 font-size:50px;
 font-weight:600;
 position:relative;
 top:10px;
}
.idea-steps-label{
 font-size:18px;
 text-align:left;
}
.draw-title{
 color:#54cbec;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:left;
 font-weight:600;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration:none !important;
}
.btn.grey {
 background: grey none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border-color: grey;
 color: #fff;
 cursor:not-allowed !important;
 pointer-events:auto !important;
}
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left{
 left: -10px;
}

#back_link .glyphicon{
 font-size:48px !important;
 color:#818285 !important;
}
#back_link .glyphicon:hover{
 color:#2abbb5 !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 #back_link {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  left:5px;
 }
 #back_link .glyphicon{
  font-size:35px !important;
 }
 .step-one, .step-two, .step-three, .step-four{
  font-size:18px;
 }  
}

.sticky {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 8px 10px;
 width:205px;
 height:200px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 border:1px #E8Ds47 solid;
 background:#f2f4ce;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
 -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
}
.sticky p {
 text-align: center;
}
.sticky textarea {
 width:184px;
 height:180px;
 background:#f2f4ce;
 border-bottom:none !important;
}
.sticky ol {
 margin: 12px;
}
.r-index{
 z-index: 0;
}
.a-index{
 z-index: 99;
}
.sticky-container {
  position: relative;
}
.sticky {
  position: absolute;
}
/*time container*/
button[data-setter] {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #F7958E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button[data-setter]:hover { opacity: 0.5; }

.time-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.setters {
  position: absolute;
  left: 85px;
  top: 75px;
}

.minutes-set {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 28px;
}

.seconds-set { float: right; }

.controlls {
 position: absolute;
 left: 37%;
 top: 52px;
 text-align: center;
}

.display-remain-time {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 32px;
 color: #fff;
}

#pause {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.play::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 22px solid #F7958E;
}

.pause::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 5px solid #F7958E;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#pause:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

.e-c-base {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 4px
}

.e-c-progress {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #18b1a0;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.7s;
}

.e-c-pointer {
  fill: #FFF;
  stroke: #F7958E;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#e-pointer { transition: transform 0.7s; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform: 0.7s; }
.sticky-note-div{
 background:#f2f4ce;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
 height:215px;
 width:22%;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:2%;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 position:relative;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.sticky-note-div img{
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top: 5px;
}
.sticky-note-div:last-child{
 margin-right:0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nob-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  right: -26px;
 }
 #slots_a {
  width:160px;
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 #slots_b {
  width:205px;
  margin-right:15px;
 }
 #slots_c {
  width:205px;
  margin-right:0px;
 }
 .time-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    .nob-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 262px;
  right: -22px;
 }
 #slots_a, #slots_b, #slots_c {
  width:210px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
 }
 .problem-text{
  visibility:hidden;
 }
}
.card{
 background:#fff;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}
.card .tab-content{
 max-width:100% !important;
 font-size:18px !important;
 min-height: 300px;
 max-height:514px;
 overflow: auto;
}
.card .nav-tabs { border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD; }
.card .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover { border-width: 0; }
.card .nav-tabs > li > a { border: none; color: #ffffff;background: #58585a; font-size:16px;font-weight:600;}
.card .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li > a:hover { border: none;  color: #58585a !important; background: #fff; }
.card .nav-tabs > li > a::after { content: ""; background: #58585a; height: 2px; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: -1px; transition: all 250ms ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease 0s; transform: scale(0);-webkit-transform: scale(0); }
.card .nav-tabs > li.active > a::after, .nav-tabs > li:hover > a::after { transform: scale(1);-webkit-transform: scale(1); }
.card .tab-nav > li > a::after { background: #58585a none repeat scroll 0% 0%; color: #fff; }
.card .tab-pane { padding: 15px 0; }
.card .tab-content{padding:20px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;">
<div id="rcorners_parent">
<div class="slots"  id="slots_a">
<div class="wrapper" ></div>
</div>
<div class="slots"  id="slots_b">
<div class="wrapper" ></div>
</div>           
<div id="spin_btn_div">
<div class="btn-container" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<button id="proceed_btn"  style="display:none;font-size:20px;" class="btn pink pink-button shooter-btn" onClick="go();">Proceed</button>
<button id="spin_btn" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;" class="btn spin spin-button shooter-btn" onClick="go();">Spin</button>
</div>
</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent...! Thank u So much...! This works perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

Use :visible Selector

Reference https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

```
$( "div:visible" ).click(function() {
  console.log($( this ));
});
```

Comment: actually am not hidding the non visible part, am just moving to top using margin top. Your code only works when all other elements are hidden

Comment: try $('divid').is(':focus');